# i am getting error typeLoadeException was unhadled by user code

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

public void TagText() {
    var jarRoot = "C:/Users/vi005/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/mongodb/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09";
    var modelsDirectory = jarRoot + "/models";

```
// Loading POS Tagger
var tagger = new MaxentTagger(modelsDirectory + "/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger");

// Text for tagging
var text = "A Part-Of-Speech Tagger (POS Tagger) is a piece of software that reads text" + "in some language and assigns parts of speech to each word (and other token)," + 
" such as noun, verb, adjective, etc., although generally computational " + "applications use more fine-grained POS tags like 'noun-plural'.";

var sentences = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(new StringReader(text)).toArray();

foreach(ArrayList sentence in sentences){

      var taggedSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
      Response.Write(Sentence.listToString(taggedSentence, false));

  }
```

}

Comment: Please, format your code correctly and add some more explanation

Comment: @JeroenHeier I'm trying to format her code well,but there have some interrupting things